# .htaccess issues: No input file specified

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Can someone help me with this? I'm feeling like I've been hitting my head against a wall for over 2 hrs now.

I've got `Apache 2.2.8 + PHP 5.2.6` installed on my machine and the `.htaccess` with the code below works fine, no errors.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|gfx|js|swf|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The same code on my hosting provider server gives me a 404 error code and outputs `only: No input file specified.` index.php is there. I know they have Apache installed (cannot find version info anywhere) and they're running PHP v5.2.8.

I'm on `Windows XP 64-bit`, they're running some `Linux` with `PHP` in `CGI/FastCGI` mode. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

PS. if that's important that's for `CodeIgniter` to work with friendly URLs.

---

Update1:

`mod_rewrite` is installed and on.

What I've noticed is that if I change in `RewriteRule` to `/index.php?$1` (question mark instead of forward slash) it goes into an infinite loop. Anyway, using question mark isn't an option as `CodeIgniter` (required) is not going to work this way.

Homepage also works when I request index.php directly: `example.com/index.php`

I'm starting to think it might be apache thinking that once the trailing slash is added it is not a file anymore but a folder. how to change such a behaviour?

---

Update 2:

I was wrong.
Apache handles these URLs correctly.
Requesting `http://example.com/index.php/start/` (homepage) or any other valid address works.
Seems that `Apache` is just not forwarding the query for some reason.

---

Update 3:

Just to be clear what I'm trying to achieve.
I want to rewrite addresses like that:

> http://www.example.com/something/ => http://www.example.com/index.php/something/
>   http://www.example.com/something/else/ => http://www.example.com/index.php/something/else/

Comment: Try some debugging with mod_rewrite’s logging feature (see `RewriteLogLevel` directive).

Comment: Upload a PHP file with the text: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` - accessing that file will print out all of the server settings including Apache version and possibly a list of Apache modules.  You'll need to ensure mod_rewrite is installed in order to use these features.

Comment: tried that. apache version is stripped out from there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is, exactly. Is it all working now? What urls are you trying to rewrite to / from?

Comment: No, not working.
Question updated.

Comment: Gumbo: not able to use logging at hosting provider server - no access to httpd.conf or vhosts.conf

Comment: Then try some other debugging like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|gfx|js|swf|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,R]` and see what the new query is.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I was beating my head up against this as well.  I'm also installing Code Igniter.

The goocher was no RewriteBase.  Here's my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Just a notice to your code: `robots\.txt` part is not needed, because of this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: I already had a `RewriteBase`, but what fixed it for me was the `?` after `index.php` on the last `RewriteRule`. This was on a Plesk panel based server running apache/php over fastcgi.

Comment: but it create problem with this function basename=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; which returns only index.php

Answer (score 28):

**The Problem**

I encountered a similar problem just now and unfortunately none of the answers in this thread helped:

Zend Framework was giving out "No input file specified.", but:

- The default RewriteBase was just fine, and adding `RewriteBase /` did not help
- It's a shared hosting server and only FastCGI is available (no ability to switch to SuPHP)
- AcceptPathInfo was on
- There was no problem with URL rewriting in general on the server

So the answer came from the following site:
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/55620/P15 [dead link]
(even though the host is not DreamHost).

**The Solution**

Apparently all you need to do is replace this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

With this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

Problem solved.

Comment: another problem you have created if you are using this function  `basename=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` which return only index.php

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: Question mark fixed it for me with getting my site to work on ISPConfig.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

After `index.php`, the question mark is important!

Answer (score 4):

Try if it works with a simpler `RewriteCond`; like one that rewrites only everything that isn't an existing file/folder/link:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: this works for the homepage: example.com/, not for anything else like example.com/something/

Comment: Oh, now I get it... you want to REDIRECT the requests instead of just REWRITING... (if I understood your update #3 correctly :) Try adding [R] into the end of the rewriterule, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

`mod_rewrite` is a bit too smart for its own good, because it tries to figure out what sort of redirect it should be doing. In this case it looks to `mod_rewrite` like you're trying to redirect to a folder, so it looks for the folder and can't find it, hence the error.

**Edit:** Just to be perfectly clear I think your best bet is to change your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

unless there is a very speciic reason why you want it to be a forward slash.

**Edit 2:** I see that you already tried this. The reason you're getting an infinite loop is because you have index.php in your rewrite condition. If you remove that you should be free of the infinite loop.

Comment: using ? mark isn't an option. CodeIgniter won't work this way.

Answer (score 3):

Go Daddy Users:

1. login to your Go Daddy Account
2. click on your hosting account.
3. go to Settings > File Extensions Management
4. change .php and .php5 to run under PHP5.2X (instead of PHP5.2xFastCGI)

SOLVED!!!!

Answer (score 2):

this code will fixed this issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess for Live Server :-

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess for Localhost :-

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Comment: The .htaccess for the live server is unchanged from the accepted answer. If there's a good reason to provide a different explanation for the Localhost you should elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the administrator of your host has disabled the ability to use Rewrite in .htaccess. They might not even have mod_rewrite installed.

Drop them an email and ask

Since this is a server configuration issue, perhaps you should ask at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

**Edit (since you are sure that the server is configured correctly)**

Have you considered tagging your RewriteCond with an end of line $?

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|gfx|js|swf|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
```

Will (based on my limited knowledge) block any url that contains index.php, css, gfx ... at the start of a url. Because you don't have a $ at the end of the regexp, it will also block any urls that continue on from there...

I.e `www.yourdomain.com/index.php/something` is not redirected, same with `www.yourdomain.com/js/something`

Perhaps you want to add a $, which will require the url to end immediately after your regexp.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|gfx|js|swf|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)$
```

Comment: No. mod_rewrite is on. What I've noticed is that if I change in RewriteRule to /index.php?$1 (question mark instead of forward slash) it goes into an infinite loop.

homepage also works when I request index.php directly:
http://www.example.com/index.php

I'm starting to think it might be apache thinking that once the trailing slash is added it is not a file anymore but a folder. how to change such a behaviour?

Comment: Re your edit.  That's the point of not having $ at the end. So that any URLs starting with what's in the brackets are not being rewritten to index.php (inc. index.php and index.php/anything/) otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Btw. I asked at SeverFault. not much luck there either and less answers/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one time I caught `no input file specified` right on action:

This causes it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.swf)$  redirect_php.php/?a=1 [last]
```

This corrected it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.swf)$  redirect_php.php?a=1 [last]
```

note the `/` before query `?`

This seems really related to AcceptPathInfo, which is about the ability to read paths after file names:

```
http://domain.com/file.php/tricky_path/?regular_query_stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question seems to attract a lot of attention I'd like to propose another answer for people having encountering the same problem and are unable to solve it with the help of the existing answers. I myself was one of those people until five minutes ago.

Always, I mean ***always*** check your server logs because they might present useful information to you.

---

After checking my server logs (Apache2.4) I found out that open_basedir caused the trouble:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/data/sites/domain/public/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/bin:/data/sites/domain/http-docs) in Unknown on line 0
>
> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

In this case, open_basedir could not handle a symbolic link I created because it points to the outside of the open_basedir settings. Either broaden the open_basedir setting to also the new location or move the required files to the inside of any allowed directory..

Answer (score 0):

You may be using Nginx, not an Apache. The error message will be the same.

echo out your sever data to be sure.

```
echo $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying all recipes from SO until I found the solution: you have to add question mark (?) after ".php", so last line of your rewrite rules will look like:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php` `?` `/$1 [L]`

There was no **?**  In my CodeIgniter setup from previous server, cause it usedpure Apache (no Nginx). And no recipes with port forwarding, nginx reconfiguration or php-fm reinstallation helped -- I tried them all on my VDS.

That simple method solved all in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the rewrite engine was conflicting with the `doc_root` directive in `php.ini`. The rewrite engine was treating the rewritten URL as a local file path and prefixing it with the document root, only to be prefixed again by PHP.

The solution was to rewrite to a relative URL, and add the PT flag. This tells mod_rewrite to pass the result to normal URL processing.

```
RewriteRule "^/(unwanted-part)/(.*)$" /$2 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am running laragon it's happening due to php.ini file, then I removed the php and install it again and it worked successfully. I think made some changes in php.ini file that's why it's displaying no input specific. After installing php.ini it fixed my issue.

```
update php.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your server has [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) disabled that is essential for that kind of URL to work properly. Try to enable it:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

---

Ok, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php(/|$) index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: looked promising, but no luck. Error 404: No input file specified.