# htaccess rewrite rules gives No input file specified

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have my app here: http://testarea.livo.co.il/views/widget.php and the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

when browsing to widget.php (above) im getting "No input file specified."

I'm hosted on godaddy so i have no access to httpd.conf.Also im running on PHP 5.3 Fast-CGI (If it makes any valuable info)

what are my errors in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14578219/594509

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1557258/1741542

Comment: Thanks damien and olaf the links where very helpful