# mod_rewrite to replace beginning of %{REQUEST_URI} for Slim Framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I have a web directory structure like so:

```
root
    /content
        /plugins
            /myplugin
                /Slim (folder containing Slim Framework)
                index.php
    /other_folder_1
    /other_folder_2
    .htaccess
    index.html
```

I'm interested in what to specify in my `.htaccess` file in order to refer to a directory that isn't actually present on the server, but actually point to the Slim app in the `/myplugin` directory.

Here are a few example URLs, which I'd like users (or myself) to be able to use in the browser's location bar, or link with in documents:

```
1. http://example.com/nonexistent_dir
2. http://example.com/nonexistent_dir/info
3. http://example.com/nonexistent_dir/info/details
```

I'm trying to rewrite these URLs to the following:

```
1. http://example.com/content/plugins/myplugin/index.php
2. http://example.com/content/plugins/myplugin/index.php/info
3. http://example.com/content/plugins/myplugin/index.php/info/details
```

...which would all actually be handled by the `index.php` Slim Framework app in the `/myplugin` directory. It's important the apparent URLs remain as they appear in the first example, without being changed in the location bar.

Here's what is currently in the `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/schedule [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /content/plugins/myplugin/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This redirects all 3 of the test examples to `http://example.com/nonexistent_dir`, using the `/` route. So my thought is that I should be capturing everything after the `nonexistent_dir`, whether it be something or nothing, and appending it to the end of the RewriteRule somehow. But I don't understand how.

I realize that using parentheses around an expression will enable me to use the contents as a variable, referred to it with `$1` (or `$2`, `$3`... for multiples), but I don't know how to apply it to this solution.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^nonexistent_dir(/.*)?$ /content/plugins/myplugin/index.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon.
 
I've made that change and tried it. When I use `http://example.com/nonexistent_dir`, I'm sent to the `/` route. Any variant with additional path info (e.g., `http://nonexistent_dir/info`) returns a `No input file specified.` message.
 
I've read a little about this, but will try to find some more about how to solve it. I get the impression it may be an apache config issue.
 
The server is running in a shared hosting environment, so I'm hoping that I'll be able to make the appropriate changes. Any further direction that you or others may have will be much appreciated.

Comment: @DerekHauffe do you know if it's related to path info (the ability to have a path *after* the PHP script)? Is it turned on?

Comment: I'm not certain, Jon. I'm guessing that it's permitted, because if I type `http://example.com/content/plugins/myplugin/index.php/info/details` in the location bar, I get the appropriate behavior, with the `/info/details` route being properly processed. So I'm pretty confident it's something to do with either my rewrite rules or my server settings. [I just noticed that in my first response to your suggestion, I used `http://nonexistent_dir/info` as a failing example. That should have been `http://example.com/nonexistent_dir/info` as the correct failing example.]

Comment: @DerekHauffe I'm not familiar with the slim framework, but it may be that it's checking the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` along with the path info, and it's seeing `/nonexistent_dir/something/foo` (even after the rewrite) and decides that it doesn't know what that is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jon. I'll take a look into that, as well as doing some searching on the `No input file specified.` message.

Comment: @DerekHauffe According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-problem-no-input-file-specified), it required a `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Thanks again, @JonLin. Using `RewriteBase /` has no effect, nor does `RewriteBase /example.com`.

Comment: I believe this answer is probably correct to the question I asked, but that some other aspect of my server is throwing off the results. I'm going to go ahead and accept this, even though I still have other problems. Thanks, Jon!

Answer (score 0):

Slim actually discards the base directory, and sets `$env['PATH_INFO']`, taking the content of this variable to match against the specified routes.

For example, lets take a `/sub/index.php` (Slim index file) and this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^somedir(/.*)?$ /sub/index.php$1 [L]
```

...and this route specification:

```
$app->route('/info', function() use ($app) { ... });
```

So, with a `GET` request to `/somedir/info`, Slim strips `/somedir` from `REQUEST_URI` and sets `$env['PATH_INFO']` with value `/info` (this is actually done in the constructor of \Slim\Environment class).

Later, the Router class will match `/info` and execute the closure function.

If you want to pass parameters via url, the route would be, for example:

```
$app->get('/info/:param', function($param) use ($app){ ... })
```

Comment: This is not the behavior of my Slim application.