# "No input file specified" Error on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I just uploaded my site to my godaddy server 
but there is an error of `No input file specified.`

I google this a lot any got a reason of this must be .htaccess file code .

I don't know what is it. how it works. here is my code of htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

how i can solve this problem?
plz help i am new to this type of coding. Any help is appreciated.
if possible link the simplest .htaccess coding tutorial....

Comment: Would this be helpful? [No input file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified) with many upvotes.

Comment: @zx81 i'm confused....

Comment: question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-issues-no-input-file-specified/38588968)

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```