# codeigniter 2.2.0 with A3M not working properly at remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-a3m

in my new project i am using codeigniter 2.2.0 and A3M 1.01 authorization library i have checked on my localhost it is working fine but when i uploaded it on remote server, home page is loaded but sign in is not working it shows following error( www.redzoon.com )

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." i contacted the
>   server administrator he said there is some problem with application.
>   so i thought there may be problem in .htaccess file. this is my
>   .htaccess file code

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /CodeIgniter2.2_A3M/
   # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
       ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

please help me where am i doing wrong, is there anything i have missed

Comment: this error can be viewed at http://www.redzoon.com/account/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have googled for about three days finally i got some clue by changing .htaccess. now i was not getting 500 internal server error instead i was getting "no input file specifed" then i searched again about this error and i found a link 
[.htaccess problem: No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-problem-no-input-file-specified)
where i got solution to my problem this is the .htaccess code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this worked for me.