# error while calling a controller in codeigniter (php)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a website in codeigniter . it is working fine on local host and on the live server it is opening the default controller normally but when i m tring to call other controller then i m getting error  of  No input file specified. everything is working fine on local host .

```
class Contact_us extends CI_Controller {

public function index()

   {

       echo  $data["header"] = $this->load->view('header');

        //$this->load->view('index',$data); 

    }   

}
```

I am calling my controller like mysitename/index.php/contact_us

Comment: What host are you using?

Comment: Do you use `index.php` in your URL?

Comment: yes i am using index.php in my url

Comment: You can check this answer [.htaccess problem: No input file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568937/2627842) There also solution for GoDaddy users.

Comment: Do you have a header controller that your trying to get data from? If so you would have to put the same header data in to the contact us. For your issue would look into codeigniter hmvc https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc much more dynamic.

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

Comment: so when you type `mysitename/index.php/contact_us` as the url, your site loads correctly, but when you try `mysitename/index.php/somthing_else` , it does not work correct?

Comment: why are you trying to echo `$data['header']` like that, if im not mistaken, you will just see `Array()` as the result. Maybe you want to pass the view as string and for that you need to place `TRUE` as a parameter in the load->view like this: `$data["header"] = $this->load->view('header', '', TRUE);`

Comment: if you go to your config.php file, what do you see for your `base_url` ?

Answer (score 0):

it works with change in htaccess file like

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

and put $config['index_page'] = ""; in the config file 
so now my site url becomes like mysitename/contact_us