# No input file specified (htaccess?)

Tags: .htaccess, server, php

I have just uploaded a prebuilt script, which when navigating to /admin and other locations I get the error 'No input file specified'.

Would anyone be able to elaborate on this?

If I can provide any further details that would help please let me know.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|install|filemanager|public|assets|css|js|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555996/no-input-file-specified or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-problem-no-input-file-specified

Comment: Thank you - I had already looked at the first, not the second. Having reviewed and trying some amendments I am no closer to a resolution unfortunately.