# .htaccess RewriteBase not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using a .htaccess to remove the index.php of my CodeIgniter project. I had it working properly in localhost but is failing  at my hosting. The structure my hosting shows me is like this:

```
/
-- domains
---- mydomain.com
------ public_html
-------- .htaccess
-------- (the rest of my CI site)
```

In localhost my .htaccess was like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myCIfolder/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I have tried:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteBase /domains/
RewriteBase /domains/mydomain.com/
RewriteBase /domains/mydomain.com/public_html/
RewriteBase /mydomain.com/
RewriteBase /mydomain.com/public_html/
RewriteBase /public_html/
```

But I couldn't make it work. I have asked to my host provider and they said MOD_REWRITE is already enabled.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1**

My index page (mydomain.con -- main controller, index function) is loading properly,but any other controller fails.

With

```
RewriteBase /
```

It shows me the error:

> No input file specified.

Any other RewriteBase shows:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mydomain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2 Server at mydomain.com Port 80

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Is there any error message you get that you can post (and or what does apache produce)? If public_html is your document root and the file index.php is found in this directory it should work with RewriteBase /, since this is what is entered between the url to your root directory and the result from your RewriteRule. The %{REQUEST_FILENAME ... tells the rule only to process anything that is not a file or a directory, which should be ok, since you want to pass any request to your front controller index.php, correct?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my question. RewriteBase / shows me "No input file specified." message only. And thank you for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it thanks to @Fuzzzzel comment which lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568937/3496016).

So I changed my .htaccess to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And it's finally working. Thank you! :)

Comment: OK, then you did not specify a file when you called your website but only typed the domain name itself. This did not find the index file (which usually has the extension .htm or .html), so you had to specify it via DirectoryIndex. Glad you figured it out.