# How to skip index.php in URL rewriting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have set WAMP up and running without too much hassle. But thing is I could not skip past `index.php` in my URL (`localhost/index.php/login` is working but `localhost/login` is not working).

Anyway my project is based on CI framework and I was using vagrant previously for hosting same project and which is working perfectly for this case. I have checked that the rewrite_module on for Apache and here it is my `.htaccess` file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please help me out from here.

Comment: You code is working on my apache.

Comment: Try as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]# notice question mark`. Also add `RevriteBase /` directive as first thing after enabling engine rewrite. If not working test without slash infront `index.php`. Btw. [this](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) is good example code you could use in CI.

Comment: @Starkeen Some explanations can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-problem-no-input-file-specified).

Comment: Actually its working on mine too on vagrant @Starkeen

Comment: I tried as you said @Tpojka but still not couldnt find any luck on it

Answer (score 3):

First of all go in your project  myproject-application->config.php

```
replace line no. 29
From
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
To
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then add .htaccess file on your root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this .htaccess file code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How's this possible mate, I'm using this same htaccess since 3 years... May be you have different problem in your code..

Comment: May be you aren't using `base_url()` in files

Comment: Have you checked it in incognito window?

Comment: Is your rewrite_module on in your apache?

Comment: Its something strange to myself. I checked it rewrite_module on and I am using base_url() in files. Even stranger thing is it was working perfectly on vagrant box.