# "No input file specified." - FastCGI, Is there a fix that can be done in the vhost?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

I discovered this error on a CodeIgniter project. The htaccess file is rewriting to /index.php/$1 [L]

I am aware that this can be fixed by modifying the rewrite rule in htaccess ([.htaccess problem: No input file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258)), however I am really looking for a server-wide fix that can be done without modifying each site's htaccess file.

So is there anything that can be added to the vhost (or somewhere else) to make FastCGI see and process the index.php file? My vhost currently looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias dev.project.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/dev.wamp/www/project"
    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        FcgidWrapper "c:/dev.wamp/bin/php/5.3/php-cgi.exe" .php
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```