# Error "No input file specified.", After update PHP Version on server from 5.3.3 to 5.6 for codeigniter on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I got an error, "No input file specified" on server after update PHP 5.3.3 to 5.6 for codeigniter.
my .htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|satellizer|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

php_flag short_open_tag on
```

and my database.php is this ...

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    //'database' => 'dod_live',
    'database' => 'copy_dogonde_dod',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

data base is also not connecting now getting mysqli error

Comment: Try with adding rewrite base in .htaccess. [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-problem-no-input-file-specified) this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check database connection first and try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost