# Laravel Deployment Issue "No input file specified."

Tags: laravel, apache, deployment, cpanel

I'm having some major issues deploying a website I have built in Laravel which is a technology I am still learning.

I built the site on a temporary subdomain (`new.example.com`) on a brand new server. I have now come to deploy it so I removed the subdomain mapping in cPanel and changed the primary domain's document root to point Laravel's `/public` folder as described [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92883/63687).

This shows what I have done:

```
new.example.com - /public_html/mainsite/public
www.example.com - /public_html/mainsite/public
```

Now when I try to access `www.example.com` I get the error message:

> No input file specified.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-issues-no-input-file-specified) but it doesn't seem to match what I have in my `.htaccess` file. I appear to have run out of talent to be able to fix this problem on my own and need help.

My questions are:

1. How can I resolve the error mentioned above?
2. Is there a better way to deploy Laravel sites to cPanel environments?
3. Have I created an XY problem for myself and I should be looking at something else to get this to work?

Comment: Did you deploy it on a shared hosting that incorporates CPanel?

Comment: No its a dedicated server that came with cpanel installed.